# How to Handle Newly Created Page in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js, and I have a page that lets users create a new page.  In other words, I can go to `/create`, and it will make a new page `/foo/123`, and redirect the user to it ... except then the user gets an error, because the new page doesn't exist (to Next).

This makes perfect sense: my `getStaticPaths` returns results for `121`, `122`, etc., but since `123` didn't exist until a second ago, Next doesn't know about it.  If I refresh `/foo/123` (on my dev site at least) the dev server *will* re-run the `getStaticPaths`, see the new record, and show `/foo/123`.

However, I'm not sure how it will handle things on my actual server, and either way I'd like to be able to forward the user on to the page they just created, right after they create it.  Is there a standard best practice for dynamically creating pages in Next.js?

I do realize that one solution would be to not use `getStaticPaths`/`getStaticProps` at all for this route ... but then I'd be missing out on server-side generation for all of the pages that *aren't* brand new.

So I guess I'm asking ... how can I use `getStaticProps`/`getStaticPaths` to generate a bunch of existing pages for a given route, but then when the user goes to that route and there is no static path, have it fall back to a dynamic route of some sort?

Comment: See the Next.js [on-demand revalidation docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#on-demand-revalidation). When you create a new page or update data for a page, you send the path to the revalidation API endpoint.

Comment: That seems promising, but I don't quite see how to use that to solve things.  Is the idea that I make a revalidation API endpoint, and then after `/create` makes the page, it should forward the user to that revalidation endpoint?  Or do I make a  (server-side) `fetch` to the revalidation URL after the create, wait for it to come back, and *then* forward to `/foo/123`?

Comment: Yes, make an API route like in the docs, and you call that endpoint on the server for revalidation. The call is done from the server to prevent exposing your secret. I typically `await create/update` > `await revalidation` > `redirect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to follow Sean W's advice (in the comments), and that might be a viable option ... but I actually found a much simpler option on the [documentation page he linked](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#on-demand-revalidation): `fallback`.

If you return an extra property `fallback: 'blocking'` from your `getStaticPaths`, like so:

```
export const getStaticPaths = () => {
    const paths = // get paths as you normally would
    return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' };
}
```

it forces Next to refresh its static paths list (without any extra API calls).

This solved the issue for me, without the need to create any extra routes (but if it doesn't work for you, see the comments from @Sean W above).